# How to pass command line arguments to a PowerShell script invoked by a doskey

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, doskey

I have a `caller.cmd` file which has a DOSKEY set like this:

```
DOSKEY startnow=call powershell getscalled.ps1
```

Now the script `getscalled.ps1` has two switch parameters defined in parameter sets like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='first')]
    [switch]$thisIsFirst,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='second')]
    [switch]$thisIsSecond
)
```

So, only one of the two parameters can be provided at a time. I want the parameter to be provided from the command line itself using the DOSKEY that I have set up. Something like:

```
startnow -thisIsFirst
```

Any help on how to achieve this? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you type `doskey /?`.

Comment: It takes decades to understand Windows. You need to read the API once a year for ten years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create macro like this(so use $1 $2... for parameters);

```
DOSKEY startnow=script.ps1 $1
```

So, you could call;

```
startnow -thisIsFirst
```

Comment: Yes, and I checked more on this and found that `$*` at the end will accept any number of arguments. But I have a weird issue. I have to use `==` instead of `=`, i.e. `DOSKEY startnow==call powershell getscalled.ps1 $*`. It doesn't work otherwise. What is the difference of `=` and `==` here? Any idea?

Comment: What is your windows version? I think you do not need that "call powershell" part.

Comment: The second = is the beginning of your command and is ignored by cmd.exe.